# How to deal with missing data in DIF analysis?

Tags: missing-data, scales, psychometrics

I would like to do a DIF analysis on a scale

The problem is that I have missing data for 10 items for the focal group

The questionnaire in question exists in two forms: a 15 item version and a 25 item version

When we collected the data from different researchers we realized that they had not all used the same version: About 100 participants filled out the 15-item questionnaire and 100 others the 25-item one (which includes the 15 items of the first one).

That makes about 20% of data missing, I don't know if I can still do something with it and I can't identify if I am in a MAR (missing at random), MCAR (missing completely at random) or MNAR (missing not at random) case.

What do you think?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You never really know if you are mcar, mar or mnar. You need to make the assumption..

Comment: I have a hard time doing just that